# Is there a way to use OpenCV functions to perform face recognition based on eye detection?

Tags: opencv, face-recognition, eye-detection

My project requires face recognition based on the availability of limited features which mainly include eyes and the forehead region.
But I am unable to find any good resources to perform the same.
There are mostly resources dealing with face detection to face recognition using opencv but I have not been able to find any resource on how I can use eye detection and its feature extraction to perform face recognition with opencv.

Any guidance regarding this problem or suggestions of alternatives would be helpful.
Thank you

Comment: https://datascienceplus.com/face-and-eye-detection-with-opencv/

Have you Gone through this?

Comment: Yes I have, I want to do recognition based on periocular region, I am actually confused about how to go about recognition after the eye detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea was to use virtual mask application on basic full face image and then to make standard face_recognition / dlib's face encodings with large 68-points model for further dlib face comparation. It works. Not 100%, especially on millions-of-images data set but better then without such approach.
https://github.com/bohdansok/Face_Recognition

Comment: Oh, will check it out! Thanks!!